# Getting matched values and non existing using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Need to get the matching target entities for existing and non existing using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1,2, 2,3],
                         'ent_src': ['TrdA, TrdB,C, D','TrdA, TrdB,C, D','TrdA, TrdB,C, D','TrdA, TrdB,C, D','TrdA, TrdB,C, D'],        
                         'ent': ['TrdA', 'TrdB','TrdF', 'TrdXX',''],                                      
                        'col': ['aaaa', 'bbbb','ccc', 'ZZZZ','ggg']})

1. If col 'ent' is in 'ent_src' then map the respective 'ent' to 'tgt_entity' else delete in the target
2. If there is no 'ent' then assign all the 'ent_src' to respective column

The tgt_entity can be achieved for the second case using below:
data = data.assign(tgt_entity=data['ent_src'].str.split(',')).explode('tgt_entity')

Expected output:    
   id   ent_src                   ent       col   tgt_entity 
0   1   TrdA, TrdB,C, D           TrdA      aaaa   TrdA
1   1   TrdA, TrdB,C, D           TrdB      bbbb   TrdB
2   3   TrdA, TrdB,C, D                     ggg    TrdA
3   3   TrdA, TrdB,C, D                     ggg    TrdB
4   3   TrdA, TrdB,C, D                     ggg    C
5   3   TrdA, TrdB,C, D                     ggg    D
```

Comment: Please clarify your second point. In the second row, the ent is blank so tgt_entity will be " TrdA, TrdB,C, D "?

Comment: Yes please, as there is no ent value/ent is Null then but there is a corresponding ent_src so need to explode this ent_src and map to tgt_entity.

Comment: There are spaces around some of the commas which you need to account for e.g. `.str.split(',\s*')`. The expected output looks like `ent` being equal or empty? e.g. `data.loc[(data['ent'] == data['tgt_entity']) | (data['ent'] == '')]` which doesn't really match the description.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
m = [e in s for s,e in zip(data["ent_src"], data["ent"])]

out = (
    data.assign(
        ent=data["ent"].where(m).fillna(""),
        tgt_entity= lambda x: x["ent"].replace("", None)
                  .fillna(x["ent_src"].str.split(",\s*")))
        .loc[m].explode("tgt_entity")
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   id          ent_src   ent   col tgt_entity
0   1  TrdA, TrdB,C, D  TrdA  aaaa       TrdA
1   1  TrdA, TrdB,C, D  TrdB  bbbb       TrdB
4   3  TrdA, TrdB,C, D         ggg       TrdA
4   3  TrdA, TrdB,C, D         ggg       TrdB
4   3  TrdA, TrdB,C, D         ggg          C
4   3  TrdA, TrdB,C, D         ggg          D
```

Comment: Some how i am getting below results instead of the expected output using above code:  3 records only instead of 6.
id          ent_src      ent   col   tgt_entity
0   1  TrdA, TrdB,C, D  TrdA  aaaa       TrdA
1   1  TrdA, TrdB,C, D  TrdB  bbbb       TrdB
4   3  TrdA, TrdB,C, D         ggg       TrdB

Comment: The output in your comment is barely readable but anyways, when I use your `data` with my code, I got the expected output (*see* : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta1XK.png).